# Laravel Product Page Filter with Load More Pagination

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, e-commerce

Currently working on ajax filter with load more button but its a lil bit buggy right now ,
as of now Load more working perfect when no filter applied , same filters are working great and rendering the data but when I load more the filtered data it shows all products without filtered result and same time when I remove filter its not showing the data .

Loadmore button html :

```
<button id="load-btn" type="submit">
<span>Load more</span>
</button>
```

Load More Clicked function

```
var page = 1;
   var clicked = false
   $("#load-btn").click( function(e) {
        page++;
        clicked=true;
        filter();
      }
     );
```

Ajax Request :

```
 function filter() {
          var url = '{{ route("front.shop.filter") }}';
                var categories = [];

          $(".category:checked").each(function(){

            categories.push($(this).val());
            console.log(categories)
            
        });
              
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                       categories:categories,
                       page: page
                      },
                    type: 'post',
                    beforeSend:function(){
                      $('.load-more').show(); // loader
                      
                      if(!clicked){
                         $('#products').html('');
                        
                      }
                    }
                }).done(function(data){
                   setTimeout(function(){ 
                      $('.load-more-skelton').hide();
                      if(clicked == 1){
                         $('#product').append(data.view);
                         clicked = false;
                          page = 1;
                      } else {
                         $('#product').html(data.view);
                      }
                   
                   }, 1500);
            
                });
       }
```

SearchController

```
public function filters(Request $request)
    {

        $products = Product::where('status' , 'active');

       
        if($request->categories){
            $products = $products->whereIn('category_id',$request->categories);
        } 

        $products = $products->latest()->paginate(8);

       
        $view = view('front.includes.view',compact('products'))->render();
        

        return response()->json(['view' => $view]); 
    }
```

As now I am confused right about pagination stuff .

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that every time JS `filter()` is called, it re-initialized `categories` variable and it's empty while being sent. If you can provide more context (input fields, etc) and how `categories` value is assigned it would be more informative

Comment: Hi I have updated my code please have a look .

Comment: @SyedKhizer I don't quite get `if(clicked == 1)` part, why in this block `page=1;` ? Does that mean that every time an user click on load more, the `page` variable will be reset to `1`, is this in your plan? Further more, providing that an user don't change filter during pagination, is the results of `console.log(categories)` the same after every click? I assume the answer is yes

Comment: For `if(clicked == 1)` part I want extend the div with new content and if not clicked then I want to extend the div which contains the product .

Comment: No I am just using the variable page for debugging which page I am on and incrementing it when load more is clicked .

Comment: I want if a user clicked on new filter type then all pagination will be set to null and the data will popup with new products and it will be paginated and it has load more button obviously for more products but when it click on load more it will populate new paginated result .

Comment: I think there is a little misunderstanding here. Every time the button is clicked, `clicked` is assigned to `true`. And in `done()` function, because `clicked` is always `true` when user click Load more, `page = 1` is executed. The `page` value is also sent to the server and `paginate()` recognises that. If `page` is not incrementing every click, how it is going to be properly paginated

Comment: Have you removed  `page = 1;` line in `done()` and try again? Give it a shot

Comment: Nothing changed , same result .